# Allow localhost endpoint in different Azure hosting options

Tags: azure

I use a small webserver for inter-process-communication between .NET and and an executable process on the same machine, i.e. a POST request to `http://localhost:3000/`

This works fine on my local machine when I allow the process with Windows Firewall.
Having tried the same on Azure Websites, I get an error (kind of expected).

Now my question is, which of the other services allows me to open a port and listen locally? All of them? (VM, Workers, Web Roles)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to open a PORT (socket) you can use either of VM, Web Role or Worker Role. You just have to be aware of the specifics of each. Just quick tip for differences:

- VM is a IaaS Service (Infrastructure-as-a-Service) - this is where you get a VM with OS and you take care of the OS from then on - updates, patches, everything
- Web/Worker Roles are PaaS Service (Platform-as-a-Service) - here you get (a fully customizable) environment under Windows OS to run your code. However about OS and Framework patches and updates someone else is taking care of.

One very good article explaining IaaS, PaaS, SaaS is [Pizza-as-a-Service](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/article/20140730172610-9679881-pizza-as-a-service). Which I recommend reading.

Then for your concrete scenario, I would advice you to go for a WebRole. You can combine WebRole with worker processes. [Here is a quick tip on how to do this](http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2010/12/how-to-combine-worker-and-web-role-in.html).

But, whenever you go for the cloud, be sure to check out the [Azure migration cheat-sheet](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/10/windows-azure-migration-cheat-sheet.html).

Comment: A Worker Role runs the local webserver without changing the firewall, so pretty easy.